# Grab most recent values from table using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Im having the below sql table structure and im trying to grab values from 2 tables using codeigniter.

```
table: salesman

id    sales_name     ref_id
1       kevin      174
2       mike       574
3       nick       777


table: sales_report

 id   salesman_id   product     purchased_date      dispatched 
 1    2             BF0214      04-November-2011        Yes
 2    2             CF0474      09-November-2011        No
 3    2             BF0111      10-November-2011        No
 4    3             BF0714      15-November-2011        Yes
 5    3             BF0435      15-November-2011        Yes
 6    2             BF0335      18-November-2011        Yes
 7    1             BF0714      22-November-2011        Yes
 8    1             BF0335      25-November-2011        Yes
```

im passing the salesman_id to the model to grab and display the values in my view.

my html table is as below

```
Ref ID   |  Salesman Name  | Last product Sold | Sold Date  | Dispatched Status
```

the problem that im having how can query to get the sales_name and ref_id from the salesman table and get the most recent product name, dispatched  and purchase_date from from the sales_report table?

eg:

```
   Ref ID   |  Salesman Name  | Last product Sold |   Sold Date         | Dispatched Status
    174            kevin            BF0335            25-November-2011       Yes
    574            mike             BF0335            18-November-2011       Yes
    777            nick             BF0435            15-November-2011       Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> GROUP BY
>
> ORDER BY

for getting this done

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) values from the `sales_report`, [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) `salesman` to get in the `sales_name` and `ref_id`, [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) the `purchased_date` (DESC to get the most recent one first instead of the oldest first), and [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm) the `salesman.id` to get it to only return one row per salesman.

```
SELECT * FROM sales_report LEFT JOIN salesman ON sales_report.salesman_id = salesman.id ORDER BY purchased_date DESC GROUP BY salesman.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find last product by two criteras: its sold date and by its id; because some products may be sold in one day. So, try this one -

```
SELECT s.ref_id, s.sales_name, sr.product, sr.purchased_date, sr.dispatched FROM salesman s
  JOIN (
    SELECT salesman_id, product, purchased_date, dispatched FROM (
      SELECT salesman_id, product, purchased_date, dispatched, IF(@salesman_id = salesman_id, @i := @i + 1, @i := 1) n, @salesman_id := salesman_id
        FROM sales_report, (SELECT @i:= 0, @salesman_id = NULL) vars
      ORDER BY salesman_id ASC, purchased_date DESC, id DESC) t
    WHERE t.n = 1
      ) sr
  ON s.id = sr.salesman_id;
```